# apache beam does not support gsutil -Z

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, gsutil

Using apache beam python SDK 2.2.
*That might be a bug.*

I have a local folder with standard csv files.
I run the following command:

```
gsutil -m cp -Z -L output.log *.csv gs://my-bucket
```

As expected, the files are uploaded to the bucket with extension *.csv with some metadata as explained in the doc.

**Problem #1:** the extension is not `.csv.gz` so `compression_type=beam.io.filesystem.CompressionTypes.AUTO` simply does not work and assume no compression (extension based).

So, if I set the compression to be UNCOMPRESSED or GZIP, I obtain an assert in `gcsio.py` `assert len(value) == size` line 642.
The content is uncompressed (maybe due to the headers gsutil sets) so the size is not read properly (the code seems to expect a compressed value/size pair but it gets uncompressed value/compressed size).

If I use 7z to gzip my csv file and manually upload to the bucket, everything works fine, the value we get is the compressed value with the compressed size.

**Problem #2:** Seems like gsutil compression is not supported by apache beam python sdk...?
Is there any work around using gsutil? i'd rather not script something to gzip before upload as i will lose the automatic decompression on download the storage offers.

PS: I use a slightly modified version of the CsvFileSource from https://github.com/pabloem/beam_utils/blob/master/beam_utils/sources.py: it reads the entire file and not line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these files are being decompressed by GCS at runtime (reading) based on content-encoding. GCS automatic decompression is currently not supported for Python SDK. Relevant issue is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1874. We'll try to look into this in the near future.

Comment: same issue indeed. thanks for the answer. unfortunately I cannot remove the header before reading as the download etc is done transparently by beam. i ll just gzip manually then.... :(